# WPF TreeView IsSelected Binding Throwing Null Reference Exception

Tags: wpf, binding, treeview, runtime-error, tabcontrol

I've got a tabcontrol that is bound to a tab collection in my view model. Right now there are 2 types of tabs and one of them has a treeview in it. When the tab is first created, the treeview selection works. When I switch tabs and come back to the tab with the treeview in it, the treeview items seem to become unbound. When I try to select one I get the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. 
BindingExpression:Path=IsSelected; DataItem='NavigationItem' (HashCode=50956576);
target element is 'TreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'IsSelected' (type
'Boolean') NullReferenceException:'System.NullReferenceException: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(
Object component, Object  value)
at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.SetValue(Object item, Object value)
at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.UpdateValue(Object value)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateSource(Object value)'
```

I'm not sure why this is occurring. When debugging through the application my model still has all of the correct data, and the treeview even displays the information from the model meaning it has to have been bound correctly when the tab was initially changed. It's just when I try to select an item after having left the tab and come back. Here's the source for my tab control and the tab in question with a treeview in it:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            ...
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentControl.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tabs:ArchitectureTabViewModel}">
                            <views:ArchitectureTab/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tabs:TestOrderTabViewModel}">
                            <views:TestOrderTab/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentControl.Resources>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

And the tab in question:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding GraphNavigationModel}">
    ...
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationTree}" Background="#00ffffff" Margin="5" BorderThickness="0" MinWidth="200">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does your `NavigationItem` class (or whatever type is in the `NavigationTree` collection) have an `IsSelected` property?

Comment: The issue is caused by OneWayToSource Binding. Change the binding in setter to Mode TwoWay and you will do fine. TreeView and OneWayToSource binding do not like each other.

Comment: @Sheridan the NavigationItem class does have the IsSelected property.

Comment: @devhedgehog switching to TwoWay mode did not make a difference.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh. Do you have a getter there? And setter? Does IsSelected have those two?

Comment: @devhedgehog it turns out that the IsSelected property setter was throwing a NullReferenceException. But thanks for your help :)

Comment: Well at least I gave you a hint. :)

Comment: In my case I had an "IsSelected" on both the item of the treeview and the VM and WPF bound to the property on the VM instead.